# UserControl inside class vs class inside UserControl for Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, user-controls

I'm working on a modular project consisting of multiple sensors, each inheriting from an abstract `Sensor` class. To configure each sensor, I have started to add a user control panel for each sensor (inherits from `UserControl`), which is loaded at runtime and displayed in a panel by the calling application.

But then I realised that to change sensor properties from the control, the `Control` class needs to have access to those properties or the sensor has to subscribe to configuration setting changes in the user control. This doesn't feel right, however, the control should be *controlling* the sensor.

What is the most elegant solution to control my sensors without creating a delegate-hell?

Should I continue on the path of:

```
class TestSensor : Sensor
{
    public UserControl ControlPanel { get; } // returns a TestSensorControl
    // ...
}
```

or should my sensors be created inside my controls:

```
class TestSensorControl : UserControl
{
    private TestSensor _sensor;
    public TestSensor Sensor {
        get {
            return _sensor;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Sensors are responsible for checking for state changes and communicating it to the calling application by signalling an `OnSensorEvent(...)` event.

Alternatively, my base `Sensor` class could inherit from UserControl, and my SensorControl can inherit from that instead, eliminating the need for an intermediate control class.

Comment: + This is a really good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id pass the sensor into control and have a subscription process.

Comment: +1 Hmm, I considered this. But if my Sensor class passes itself to its control which is contained within itself, eg. SensorControl(this), it seems circular or redundant? Having the sensor inside the control means I don't have to add any more subscription methods.

Comment: i woul dnot have the control inside the sensor. I would have the control wrapping a sensor ... when you add a sensor to the control then the control can change the sensors values. If you want the sensor to be able to effect the control then i would use events. the control can then contain some decision logic and possibly adjust the sensor. I tend to code things like this against interfaces. Ie i would write an interface for the sensor.

Comment: I don't want the sensor to affect the control, but I would like the control to subscribe to sensor events like the calling application.

Comment: oh ok in that case we are overcomplicating things. What you really have are a collection of controls and a collection of sensors. All you need to do is wire them up. These simply form collections of objects, the rest of your program then drives the thing. Ther is no need to have one of them as a proprty of another. Also consider that when an even is fired a reference to the object is also present ... ie it may not be necessary to have a 1:1 relationship in the number of sensors and controls.

Comment: I might create a class/struct to hold both a sensor and a control that also wires them up and have some kind of a collection of these.

Comment: Its a tricky decision without gettign the whole context. Essentially it may be simpler to manage by having the sensors as part of the cotnrol and using events to get the information to the control. However that doesn't model the situation which is what i was trying to do above. My first solutino is the easiest. However you clearly have some kind of looping code somewhere which can begin to favour the collection approach (as you are probably already iterating through a collecdtion of sensors).

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you should keep your non-ui Sensor class which can be used by ui and non-ui controllers, and no need to create a base UserControl for every initialization of Sensor class.

I would suggest using inherited controllers(Sensors are created in Controllers).
You can create a generic `class SensorControl : UserControl` ui and inherit from that class `class TestSensorControl : SensorControl`. That can save time and code dublicates.

You can define an abstract Sensor type in SensorControl and assign events in the constructor to be overridden.

Good luck

Comment: Agreed, it's best to keep my non-ui sensor on its own so I can use it in other applications. On a side-note, since I'm using StructureMap for IoC, is there an elegant way of using IoC to provide (via a factory?) the correct type of UserControl depending on the type of sensor? Or is that better served by having each derived sensor return the correct type?

Comment: Yep ObjectFactory should work in this case. 
You can also add your SensorControl class a static function like: 'static SensorControl Create(Sensor s){}' and return the correct type of SensorControl based on Sensor in this func.